# Crackling sound on HDMI ATI HD7790 Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, sound, ati, hdmi

I am new on Linux but I try to start use, however this if my first big problem. On my card I am not able to use HDMI for sound. I have crackling sound. This is info about my hardware:
1) By typing `lspci` come out this information:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 06)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x16 Controller (rev 06)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI (rev 05)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #2 (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev d5)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev d5)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev d5)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #1 (rev 05)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation C220 Series Chipset Family H81 Express LPC Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Bonaire XT [Radeon HD 7790/8770 / R9 260 OEM]
01:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device aac0
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 06)
04:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev 41)
```

2) With the command `cat /proc/asound/cards`:

```
 0 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                      HDA Intel PCH at 0xf0a10000 irq 45
 1 [Generic        ]: HDA-Intel - HD-Audio Generic
                      HD-Audio Generic at 0xf0860000 irq 47
```

3) With the command `aplay -l`

```
karta 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], urządzenie 0: ALC887-VD Analog [ALC887-VD Analog]
  Urządzenia podrzędne: 1/1
  Urządzenie podrzędne #0: subdevice #0
karta 1: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], urządzenie 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Urządzenia podrzędne: 1/1
  Urządzenie podrzędne #0: subdevice #0
karta 1: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], urządzenie 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Urządzenia podrzędne: 1/1
  Urządzenie podrzędne #0: subdevice #0
karta 1: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], urządzenie 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Urządzenia podrzędne: 1/1
  Urządzenie podrzędne #0: subdevice #0
karta 1: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], urządzenie 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Urządzenia podrzędne: 1/1
  Urządzenie podrzędne #0: subdevice #0
karta 1: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], urządzenie 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
  Urządzenia podrzędne: 1/1
  Urządzenie podrzędne #0: subdevice #0
karta 1: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], urządzenie 11: HDMI 5 [HDMI 5]
  Urządzenia podrzędne: 1/1
  Urządzenie podrzędne #0: subdevice #0
```

I have already tested, but not solve problem:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="radeon.audio=1" in /etc/default/grub
```

and load-module `module-udev-detect tsched=0`
Any idea what should I do?